# The usage and meaning of "to make for something"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-usage

I read in a book a sentence *"**Winston made for the stairs**. It was no use trying the lift"*. The understanding seems to be clear. I can think of a man who decided to use the stairs to lift upstairs. There is also a picture of a man going towards the stairs. In such a scenario I can think of it as a synonym for *"to head towards"*.

I tried to make up simple sentences with *"to make for"*, but I couldn't (*Let's make for Tim!*, for example). That particular context is the only thing I can think of. Finally, I have realized that the concept, the idea behind it is unclear to me.

**What does it actually mean?** How to use it?

If I was right about guessing the meaning, **can it mean something else?**

Comment: Yes, it [means what you think](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-for) - but we make for a place, not a person.

Comment: @KateBunting don't know why I didn't search in the dictionary in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: @KateBunting - I don't see why I can't say 'When the dog growled the little boy made for his mother'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I suppose so, but I'd find _he ran to his mother_ more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out *"to make for somewhere/something"* is a phrasal verb [meaning](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-for) *"to move towards the place"*.

Comment: It does indeed mean "to move towards a place", but it usually carries the nuance that the actor is moving in a hurry, and is possibly being chased either literally or metaphorically by a pursuer.

Comment: I'm not convinced ***to make for** [destination]* particularly implies *in a hurry, being chased* any more than ***to head for** [home].* It's just *make [**one's way**] home*, at whatever pace seems contextually appropriate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes. context can supply any nuance intended. When I start telling jokes, my friends usually make for the bar. When we were out walking in the Lake District, we decided to slowly make for Beatrix Potter's cottage.